# Creating US Map Including State Borders in ggvis

Tags: r, rstudio, interactive, ggvis

I'm attempting to make a US map that I can later add interactive layers to. Based on the polygon created, there seems to be an order issue, however; I've ordered them a few different ways, and none of them seemed to work properly. Any help would be appreciated.

```
library(ggplot2) 
library(ggvis) 
library(dplyr) 

mdat<-map_data("state") 

mdat %>% 
  arrange(group,order) %>% 
  ggvis(x=~long,y=~lat) %>% 
  layer_paths()
```

Comment: Perhaps like this. `mdat %>% group_by(group) %>% ggvis(x=~long,y=~lat) %>% layer_paths() `

Comment: I've got extended examples of how to do this (both the map and interaction) [here](https://rud.is/b/2014/12/29/making-static-interactive-maps-with-ggvis-using-ggvis-maps-wshiny/). For more complex shapefiles, I've had to do `group_by(group, region)` as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I yanked a bit from the post I linked to for a more complete example (that includes using a much saner projection for the contiguous 48 US states):

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggvis)
library(dplyr)
library(rgdal)
library(httr)

# decent US shapefile and httr lets us only d/l when needed
stop_for_status(GET("http://eric.clst.org/wupl/Stuff/gz_2010_us_040_00_500k.json",
                write_disk("us.geojson"), progress()))

states <- readOGR("us.geojson", "OGRGeoJSON")
states <- states[!states$NAME %in% c("Alaska", "Hawaii", "Puerto Rico", "District of Columbia"),]
states_aea <- spTransform(states, CRS("+proj=laea +lat_0=45 +lon_0=-100 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +a=6370997 +b=6370997 +units=m +no_defs"))

states_map <- fortify(states_aea, region="NAME")

states_map %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  ggvis(~long, ~lat) %>%
  layer_paths(strokeOpacity := 0.5, strokeWidth := 0.5) %>%
  hide_axis("x") %>% hide_axis("y") %>%
  set_options(width=960, height=600, keep_aspect=TRUE)
```

[image]